# Custom YQL table for Tumblr likes

Tags: json, api, tumblr, yql

I'm trying to make a custom YQL table to access a user's likes through the Tumblr API. I made the following table in the YQL editor and saved it as `tumblr.likes`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table xmlns="http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/schema/table.xsd">
  <meta>
    <author>nonphoto</author>
    <documentationURL>http://www.tumblr.com/docs/api</documentationURL>
    <sampleQuery>select * from {table} where username='XXX' api_key='XXX'</sampleQuery>
  </meta>
  <bindings>
    <select itemPath="response.liked_posts" produces="JSON">
       <urls>
           <url>http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{username}.tumblr.com/likes</url>
       </urls>
       <inputs>
         <key id="username" type="xs:string" paramType="path" required="true" />
         <key id="api_key" type="xs:string" paramType="query" required="true" />
       </inputs>
    </select> 
 </bindings>
</table>
```

If this is correct then I should be able to type this query into the YQL console and get a JSON response back from Tumblr:

```
use "XXX" as tumblr.likes;
select * from tumblr.likes where username='XXX' and api_key='XXX';
```

But `null` appears in the results entry of the response, even if debug and diagnostics are checked to prevent caching. The response even shows the correct URL, which works if I just copy and paste it into my browser. Am I missing something? Here's an example response:

```
{
 "query": {
  "count": 0,
  "created": "2016-01-15T21:44:36Z",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "diagnostics": {
   "url": [
    {
     "execution-start-time": "2",
     "execution-stop-time": "8",
     "execution-time": "6",
     "id": "579e13ad-a7c3-4eea-81d9-41fda5caf243",
     "content": "http://sherpa-bcp5903.dht.yahoo.com:4080/YDHTWebService/V1/get/yql.global/store%3A%2F%2FoSSGByQMlFLQhMqNCwUcp1"
    },
    {
     "execution-start-time": "14",
     "execution-stop-time": "1137",
     "execution-time": "1123",
     "id": "ffab25db-521f-4795-9220-a82e2ac33a9d",
     "content": "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/XXX.tumblr.com/likes?api_key=XXX"
    }
   ],
   "publiclyCallable": "true",
   "user-time": "1146",
   "service-time": "1129",
   "build-version": "0.2.942"
  },
  "results": null
 }
}
```

Comment: You want to store `liked_count` from the response in your query: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#blog-likes

Comment: @mikedidthis That entry doesn't exist. I will add an example of the response.